# `r` keyboard is refreshing expo js application. how to stop this?

Tags: react-native, expo

No idea when and how this started but if I build any expo.js application on my iOS and press the `r` key, the app is refreshing. I was typing in the input field something when I mention this.

What is this, and how to stop it?  :)

(It's Expo SDK 47 but 46 is doing the same)

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be related to upgrading to Xcode 14.1. Unfortunately I don't have a solution but I would keep my eyes on https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/19911.